# Creating a footer with icons

Tags: html, css

I have managed to get a static footer installed on my site, but right now it's just an empty bar. I want to put a row of custom social media icons in the footer so they run horizontally across the bottom of my page.This is what I have so far:

CSS:

```
.sticky-bar {
background: #000;
bottom: 0;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 700;
left:0;
margin: 0;
opacity: 0.9;
padding: 0;
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index:99999;
}

.sticky-bar-inner {
margin:0 auto;
padding: 20px 0;
text-align: center;
width:90%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sticky-bar">
<div class="sticky-bar-inner">
</div>
```

I just need to know what I need to add in order to achieve my row of icons in, what is now an empty black bar along the bottom of my site. www.salvageinteriors.com

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why not put a few `img` tags wrapped in `a` tags in the footer?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using an unordered list and display it horizontally.

```
<ul id="footerlist">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="iconPinterest.jpg></img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="iconfb.jpg></img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="icongplus.jpg></img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="icontwitter.jpg></img></a></li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
#footerlist li
{
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Just adjust the padding to control the spacing of the items

Answer (score 0):

You have unclosed div close that div first.

```
<div class="sticky-bar">
<div class="sticky-bar-inner"><!--here--->
</div>
```

You can align horizontally to the images like this

```
<div class="sticky-bar">
<div class="sticky-bar-inner"><img /><img /><img /></div>
</div>
```

And assign the `display: inline-block;` to `img`